# Converting a constructor name to string in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, string-conversion

I have the following type definitions in my code:

```
type tag =
| Head
| Title
| Body
| H1
| P;;

type domtree =
| Empty
| Node of tag * string * domtree list;;
```

I need to print the tags along with the strings. But I couldn't find any way to convert the tag (the constructor names in the first type definition) into strings and concatenate them with the string part of the domtree. Is there any specific way to do this? Does OCaml provide a way to convert non-inbuilt types into strings? I found a similar question in here but I didn't quite understand it.

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't be rolling your own DOM tree, you should just use a library that does that already.  Second, have a look at `ppx_deriving`, since it does exactly this.

Comment: Actually it was in one of my assignments to define a type domtree. And I'm a beginner in Ocaml so I am not supposed to use ppx_deriving..

Comment: You have to write it directly then, `let to_string = function | Head -> "head" | ...`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such a facility built in OCaml and you will need to write yourself the conversion function `tag_to_string : tag -> string`.

It is easy to generate the body of this string automatically, for instance, use this `sed` one-liner:

```
sed -e 's/\| \(.*\)/| \1 -> "\1"/'
```

and paste your tag definition in its standard input. It yields

```
| Head -> "Head"
| Title -> "Title"
| Body -> "Body"
| H1 -> "H1"
| P;; -> "P;;"
```

and you just have to clean the `;;`.

There is a lot of other solutions to define this boilerplate code, I also love to use Emacs macros for this.